# Saving (multiple) meta values of a select field

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am having trouble to save the meta data included in a Select field box. Just an example (hooked at function.php to the single product setup page):

```
(...)


    <select style="width:100%" id="_receita" name="_receita[]" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="<?php _e( 'Search for a product', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
            <?php
                echo '<option value="TEST"> TEST </option>';
                echo '<option value="TEST1"> TEST1 </option>';
                echo '<option value="TEST2"> TEST2 </option>';
                ?>
            </select>

    // few others custom fields:
   <?php $ingrediente_x_quantidade = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_ingrediente_x_quantidade', true ); ?>  
            <input placeholder="<?php _e( 'Ingrediente', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" type="text" class="ingrediente" id ="_ingrediente" name="_ingrediente" value="<?php echo $ingrediente_x_quantidade[0]; ?>" style="width: 90%;" />
            <input placeholder="<?php _e( 'qnt.', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" type="number" name="_quantidade" id="_quantidade" class = "quantidade" value="<?php echo $ingrediente_x_quantidade[1]; ?>" step="any" min="0" style="width: 25%;" />

(...)
```

To save the datas, I am including at function.php:

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields' );
    // Save Fields
    add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields_save' );


function woo_add_custom_general_fields_save( $post_id ){

// Custom Field
 $ingrediente_x_quantidade =  array( esc_attr( $_POST['_ingrediente'] ), esc_attr( $_POST['_quantidade'] ) );
 update_post_meta( $post_id, '_ingrediente_x_quantidade', $ingrediente_x_quantidade );

 // Select Field
 foreach ($_POST["_receita"] as $receita) {
 update_post_meta($post->ID, "_receita", $receita);
        }

        }
```

I am getting everything OK for the custom fields ("_ingrediente_x_quantidade"), but for the select field, "_receita" I am getting an empty array:

```
[_ingrediente_x_quantidade] => Array
(
[0] => a:2:{i:0;s:19:”Aveia, flocos, crua”;i:1;s:3:”113″;}
)

[_receita] => Array
(
[0] =>
)
```

What I am doing wrong? I am pretty new to coding!

Answer (score 0):

I see one problem in storing data using foreach with same key and post ID for every record...

Try use this at base:

```
update_post_meta($post->ID, "_receita", serialize($receita));

$receita = unserialize(get_post_meta($post->ID, "_receita", true));
```

*It would also be good to use a check to an empty array...*

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried your code (without the check of emptiness for now, but I will add later... when it is working)
Still not right. Now I get:
`[_receita] => Array
(
[0] => s:4:”b:0;”;
)`

Don't know why, it seems not to find the right field (id="_receita")

Comment: If I click in one of the items at the field it saves only this item. I need to save all of them, but how???